# What code can I add to make this sentence appear on my French site?

Tags: javascript

I have a snippet of code that I need help with. I am looking to make sure that this **Join the Movement** line shows up in French on my French website. Right now everything else is being translated but I wanted to know what code can I add to make sure this shows up in the other language?

```html
<div class="hero-unit">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        {% if hero_graphic or hero_text %}
          <div class="hero-text">
            {% if options.pledge_now_url %}
            <div class="hero-pledge-button">
              <a href="{{options.pledge_now_url}}" style="background-image: url('{{site.theme.link}}/assets/dist/img/arrow-right.png');font-size: 22px;">Join the Movement</a>
            </div>
            {% endif %}

{% if constant('ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE') == 'fr' %}
            <style type='text/css'>@media (min-width: 769px) { .hero-unit .hero-text-plain { font-size: 60px; } .hero-unit .hero-text-formatted .line { font-size: 30px; }}</style>
            {% endif %}

            {% if hero_text and post.get_field('hero_text_smart_formatting') %}
              <div class="hero-text-formatted">
                {{ hero_text|smart_hero_formatting }}
              </div>
            {% elseif hero_graphic and hero_text %}
              <img src="{{hero_graphic['url']}}" alt="{{hero_text}}" />
            {% elseif hero_graphic %}
              <img src="{{hero_graphic['url']}}" alt="{{hero_graphic["alt"]}}" />
            {% elseif hero_text %}
              <span class="hero-text-plain">{{hero_text}}</span>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you saying you want it to sometimes be French and sometimes English, based on the constant('ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE') ?

Comment: Please also tag the server framework. ASP? It has nothing to do with JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the translation is correct, but as far as I understood your problem, the following modification should solve it.

```
<div class="hero-unit">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    {% if hero_graphic or hero_text %}
      <div class="hero-text">
        {% if options.pledge_now_url %}
        <div class="hero-pledge-button">
          {% if constant('ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE') == 'fr' %} 
            <a href="{{options.pledge_now_url}}" style="background-image: url('{{site.theme.link}}/assets/dist/img/arrow-right.png');font-size: 22px;">Joignez-vous au mouvement</a>
          {% else %}
            <a href="{{options.pledge_now_url}}" style="background-image: url('{{site.theme.link}}/assets/dist/img/arrow-right.png');font-size: 22px;">Join the Movement</a>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if constant('ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE') == 'fr' %}
        <style type='text/css'>@media (min-width: 769px) { .hero-unit .hero-text-plain { font-size: 60px; } .hero-unit .hero-text-formatted .line { font-size: 30px; }}</style>
        {% endif %}

        {% if hero_text and post.get_field('hero_text_smart_formatting') %}
          <div class="hero-text-formatted">
            {{ hero_text|smart_hero_formatting }}
          </div>
        {% elseif hero_graphic and hero_text %}
          <img src="{{hero_graphic['url']}}" alt="{{hero_text}}" />
        {% elseif hero_graphic %}
          <img src="{{hero_graphic['url']}}" alt="{{hero_graphic["alt"]}}" />
        {% elseif hero_text %}
          <span class="hero-text-plain">{{hero_text}}</span>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A ternary or better: a lookup table would save a lot of code.